# AWS : need to redirect loadbalancer with port 443 to 127.0.0.1:3004 instance on my Ubuntu server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server, amazon-elb

I have secured domain `https://api.mydomain.com` and I have pointed to `my-loadbalancer.com`. The target group of this load balancer has once instance where are node API is running `http://127.0.0.1:3004`. All I am struggling to this is access my API from `https://api.mydomain.com` but that does not seem to work out.

My current configurations are

1. List item In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

2.Enabling all the necessary modules

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_http
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
$ sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

3. My `.htaccess` file on the root folder

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       Options +FollowSymLinks
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-loadbalancer.com$
      RewriteRule (.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3004/\$1 [P]
   </IfModule>
   ```
4. apache.conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

   ```
   Listen 80
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyRequests Off
       ServerName my-loadbalancer.com
       ServerAlias my-loadbalancer.com
       ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3004/
       ProxyPassReverse / 127.0.0.1:3004/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

I don't know maybe I am missing any configuration for https.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

See the directions for [ModProxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html). You want a reverse Proxy, which means you need "ProxyPass" directive, not a "ReWriteRule".